# How do i connect to topic/queue via postman for a spring boot WebSocket app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

1. I want to subscribe to /topic/greetings. how do i do that in postman using raw method and socket.io?
2. Is there any other alternative for testing websockets locally?

My code is from here.
[Spring boot getting started websocket app](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Only difference is my WS config class.

Im connecting to websocket in postman: **ws://localhost:8080/greetings** and then i don't really know what should i do.

```
package com.example.messagingstompwebsocket;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/greetings");
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Comment: For now Postman does not support STOMP, only RAW. So for this day you can connect and send message without any additional methods (subscriber, publisher, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this website to test web sockets locally:
http://jxy.me/websocket-debug-tool/