# Connect to a websocket using Postman in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket

I am new to Java, and new to websockets. I am trying to confirm that [a spring boot tutorial I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4lqTmFmbAM) has yielded working code. My goal is to confirm that it works so when I move onto building the browser portion, I can already see what a working version looks like.

My postman request is to `ws://localhost:8080/cat`

I expect this controller endpoint to be hit:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/cat")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage hatResponse(@Payload final ChatMessage chat) {
        System.out.println("hat");
        return chat;
    }
}
```

And here is my `WebSocketConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/cat"); // shouldn't this expose "cat" endpoint?
    registry.addEndpoint("/cat").withSockJS(); 
  }

}
```

I tried [mimicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258024/how-do-i-connect-to-topic-queue-via-postman-for-a-spring-boot-websocket-app) [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081840/springboot-websocket-testing-with-postman) [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69425947/spring-boot-with-websocket-and-postman) but [so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75443412/spring-boot-websocket-with-stomp-connectivity-using-postman-how-to-consume-spri) I'm not getting any response other than:

```
Error: Unexpected server response: 404
Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/cat
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: uwNdTzo+d0HSl70zn1OajA==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: localhost:8080
Response Headers
Vary
0: Origin
1: Access-Control-Request-Method
2: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 04 Apr 2023 01:45:34 GMT
```